# User as a model in Google App Engine's `webapp`

Tags: google-app-engine, orm

I'm using Google App Engine in Python using Google's `webapp` framework.

I want to have `User` as a model in my app, so I can give it various properties. e.g. I want to give it a boolean property `active`. But since `webapp` has its own way of handling users, I don't know how to do that so I am using `webapp`'s users but I'm still able to define my properties on them. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to create a second model-- e.g. a SiteUser model, and then make a field on SiteUser to relate it with the corresponding user that the framework provides.  You could then add whatever properties you wanted onto the SiteUser model.

Wherever you currently check the properties on the framework-provided user, you could retrieve the corresponding SiteUser and check its properties.